# Using third party code within Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I want to use a small library within the Zend Framework (simple_php_dom, for what it's worth).

Should I just stick it in library/, include it where I want to use it (like in a specific controller) like `include('library/foo.php');` and have at it?

If not, how should I do it? What's the "Zend Framework" way of doing something like this?

Comment: is there a reason why you are not going to use `Zend_Dom_Query`?

Comment: The only reason would be that I already have the code working based on simple_php_dom. I'm hoping to "plug and play" and avoid messing around with another, albeit similar, solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the library doesnt support PEAR conventions its not really easy to hook it up to the autoloader, so i would just manually `require_once` it in the controller or model that uses it. If it was used extensively I might make a wrapper class to proxy calls through and autoload that (that class having the `require_once`).

Comment: That's useful to know... that the autoloader needs a library to support PEAR conventions. Thx. I'll accept this after letting the question "ferment" a bit longer.

Comment: Well it doesnt have to support PEAR conventions, but you need something you can inflect from, otherwise you need to push your own autoloader, which is a lot of work given we are only talking about a single file with this particular lib.